# Concatenation of commands in SAGA grid calc

Tags: saga, grids-graticules, concatenation

My goal is to mask pixels with chosen value, for example if `g1` is equal to `x1,x2,x3` the resulting pixel has to be set to 1 otherwise to 0.

Through grid calculator I've tried this command:

`eq(g1, (x1 or x2 or x3))`

It works if I use only one condition, but as soon as I add `or x2 or x3` it gives an error. Any ideas? I'm probably just writing things uncorrectly or I maybe have to use another Saga Tool.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with SAGA grid calculator but maybe this idea will useful:

`eq(g1, x1) or eq(g1, x2) or eq(g1, x3)`

Comment: I just tried but unfortunately is not working, thanks anyway